# how to extend a raster plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

I wouldd like to do a raster plot with :

- x scale: 24hours
- y scale: 40 days (with the real Date)
- fill: number of participants active at the same time

This is an example of my data (here the time is in seconds, but I also have it as %H:%M%S if it's better?):

| Date | Time | Active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-02 | 84400 | 5 |
| 2021-03-02 | 84415 | 6 |
| 2021-03-02 | 84420 | 6 |

This is the forumla I used:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = Acti2 , aes(x = Time, y = Date, fill = Active)) + xlim(0,86400)+
  coord_quickmap()
```

This is the graph I obtained:
[image]

Why is it on a "line" and not a "square" ? How do I make it larger so that we can see hour per hour?
Thank you.

Comment: Why are you adding coord_quickmap? That is for geographic maps. Remove it an all should be fine

Comment: Ohhhh I was using this code for something else and did not realized that coord_quickmap will only works for maps.... Thank you, I was becoming crazy!!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = Acti2 , aes(x = Time, y = Date, fill = Active)) + xlim(0,86400)
```